# Different Newtonsoft.Json.dll dotnet publish vs publish with Visual Studio

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-publish, visual-studio-publish

I have a **.NET Core Web Application** with target framework **.netcoreapp2.0**.

If i publish my application via Visual Studio (folder profile) I get a different `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` then with the command  `dotnet publish --configuration Release --output D:/publish/Frontend /property:PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest=false`

**VS publish version**:

[image: VS publish version]

**dotnet publish version**:

[image]

The created file `AutomaticConfirmationWebfrontend.deps.json` has always this dependency:

```
"runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard1.3/Newtonsoft.Json.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "10.0.0.0",
            "fileVersion": "10.0.1.20720"
          }
        }
```

This results in a problem for my CI/CD process where I publish my app with the command `dotnet publish`. If I open the website I get an error message that the assembly ***Newtonsoft.JSON 10.0.0.0 could not be found***. If i copy manually the DLL with version 10.0.0.0 to the application folder it works! Debugging my application locally works also fine!

I have no Newtonsoft NuGet package installed. I think I am using the built in package from .NET Core.

In my `Startup.cs` I have the following line of code:

```
services.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```

I need this for lowercase JSON objects. I have imported this namespace:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization
```

Anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: Same issue, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I did 3 steps:

1. Upgraded to netcoreapp3.1
2. Removed all nuget packages from `C:\Users\******\.nuget\packages`
3. Installed the latest MSBuild installer

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it may help someone in future. Within the solution some other (other project) **NuGet** package also depending **Newtonsoft.Json.dll**. Check all your NuGet package dependencies especially Testing projects which may be mapped with low version **Newtonsoft.Json.dll**. (Refer below pic).

[image]

If that is the problem, then you can map **.csproj** file in your publish command like below,

```
dotnet publish src/myproject.csproj --configuration Release --output D:/publish/Frontend /property:PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest=false
```